# How can I achieve in CSS background with image that has 50% width and it has bottom and part of the left border?

Tags: css, background-image

I need to achieve something like that:

where this grey square is actually an image, that can be changed.
it has to be done by background, I cannot place simply img there.
I tried to achieve this with linear gradient, which will be easy if I can just set the background for specific area, but the fact that the what you can see in the image below it is just right 50% of the background complicates this. I tried different solutions for some time and I am clueless.

[image: background image with some borders]

Comment: share your attempt with the linear gradient

Comment: I added an answer (maybe you can use it), but you should always share what you've tried (and didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

You could use **CSS grid** to get the visuals in your image:

```js
const img = document.getElementById('img')
img.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://placekitten.com/200/300')"
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 10px 50%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr calc(50% - 10px) 50px 10px 1fr
}

.img-wrapper {
  grid-column: 3 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  background: red;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

.partial-border {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="partial-border"></div>
  <div id="img" class="img-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```